# Python development environment for web applications (Django)

Tags: python, django, eclipse, ide

the more I read the worse it gets... I am starting out with Python and I cannot make my 
mind up on how to set up my dev environment. I want to use Python and Django to build web applications.

Ideally, I'd love to use and IDE on Win7 (which would help with tooltips and help about methods, classes, etc) and have the web app run on a virtual linux machine (need apache+mysql). I have downloaded the turnkey linux appliance for Django and it seems to work fine.

So, in the end, it is unclear to me if people here are recommending to edit my code on the same machine where the app runs. I'd prefer to code on the Win7 machine and then publish the app/files on the fly to the linux virtual box, then accessing the app via the browser.

This is the setup for my current php project at work and I think it works perfectly.

Please clarify if people normally code and run their web apps all on one machine only or not.
Thank you!

Comment: Deploy using version control.

Comment: If it is working for you I dont see any problem with your setup.

Comment: Is there any specific question, or are you just asking for opinions? Your question is rather close to what is considered "not constructive" round here...

Comment: I think I got the answer now. Thank you for your kind help. I believe many people like me might have "silly" questions. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how it can be unclear to you "if people here are recommending to edit my code on the same machine where the app runs". The easy answer is **no, no way, never, ever**. There can be no ambiguity about that.

**Edit** Ah, apologies for the misunderstanding - you clarify in the comments that you're not talking about your production environment. In that case, yes it is a perfectly good idea - even preferable - to edit on the same machine as your development app is running. There's no reason not to, and it makes life a whole lot easier.

Note you shouldn't really use Apache in development: it requires a lot of configuration, and doesn't automatically reload after code changes without even more configuration. Use the development server. And in case you were concerned, all of this runs perfectly well on a Windows machine.

Comment: please, I am not here for aguing. I am here to get help. Please explain how to set up my environment. Any example is welcome.

Comment: I think the advice is to develop on the same _type of machine_ as where the app runs, meaning "use the same versions of the operating system, processor type, development tools, libraries".

Comment: maybe there's a misunderstaing: I am not talking about a production env. I am just setting up my dev env. I am trying to learn the language and django framework. I'll probably just install everything on one machine Python+IDE+Django+Apache+mySQL, it would make things easier. Thank you

Comment: Thank you Daniel for the clear explanation. In fact I thought the standard dev server would be crap (excuse my french). If it's fine for dev, then I'll use it. I assume the DB can still run somewhere else (on the virtual linux box). The reason is simple: on my win7 machine I have another env (PHP), with its db and so on. The apps are delivered by a 32bit Wampserver (apache+mysql).

Comment: In fact, if I recollect correctly, I had started by installing Python (64bit) and Django. But when it came to the apache adapter I was not able to install/cfg correctly. I then found out I was trying to mix 32 and 64bit apps. So I disinstalled the whole lot. I then installed the Turnkey linux virtual box which comes with Django preinstalled and cfg. And I could just start developing on that box. I like Vim, but I think it would be nicer to have some help from and IDE since I know almost nothing about Python yet. so I am going to start from scratch

Comment: In the end, tell me if I'm wrong: on win7 I shall install Python, then Django, then Aptana+plugins. Use the dev server provided and host the db on the virtual linux box. right?  :)

Comment: just use sqlite3 hosted on win7 unless you need something it doesn't support.  And have a look at virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper (not sure if wrapper works on windows though).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comment. Personally, I use Aptana Studio (http://www.aptana.com/) alongside GIT to have local version control (integrates well into Aptana). From there on, it is easy to either deploy locally or push the changes to a remote GIT repo.

Comment: BTW, actually Aptana for the most part integrates PyDEV (http://pydev.org/) into Eclipse.

Comment: thank you. Yes, I have downloaded Aptana. I do not need any version control right now. I just want to get my hands dirty and start playing with Python and Django.

Comment: Well, GIT actually is nice because you can run it locally and can track your changes (and revert them, if you break stuff :)). Also, GIT helps when accidently deleting single files (if you delete the whole directory, that still breaks stuff ;-))

Comment: OK, thank you Ben. I would like to run Apache and mySQL on the linux box. Basically I'd like to deploy my Django app on it. And see it run though the web. In my php dev, I use Dreamweaver. I edit the files locally on my win machine, then when I'm ready, I publish the site on the linux box. Is it possible/reasonable to do that in  Aptana and Django?

Comment: While developing, I would suggest running the Django app stand-alone w/o the Apache server - this allows you to see errors directly on the console. Just start django with `runserver` (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#runserver-port-or-address-port). As far as publishing goes, you can commit to a remote GIT repo on the linux host and automatically export them to the working directory of django. When using runserver, django reloads files that were changed during runtime (very useful because you don't have to restart the server everytime..)

Comment: Thank you Ben. I think I will have a look and try to integrate Git with Aptana